# Desktop fades when no activity

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop

Recently, I corrupted my `explorer.exe` while modifying the icons. I had a backup of the original explorer.exe, so I went into elevated command prompt via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + *File > Run new task* in Task Manager (elevated command prompt). I restored the `explorer.exe` to its original one, but for some reason, now when I go to my desktop, I have a black background.

Along with that problem, the desktop fades to black in one second if there is no activity on the desktop. If I open a window on the desktop, it wont fade to black. If I draw a big enough selection box with my mouse on the desktop with no window open, the desktop will stay open until I let the selection box go. When the desktop is black, I can still click and select my desktop icons (if I click in the right place).

I think this is the weirdest problem I've ever had with Windows, it can't be anything with drivers or it would do it with everything. So with what I just said "or it would do it with everything" I mean to say, everything else works perfectly fine, apps, start screen, etc.

Comment: Try running `sfc /scannow`, it will check your system files and attempt to fix them for you in case of any problems.

Comment: Sounds like you should use Windows ability to check your system's image integrity to your advantage.  Start with `/sfc scannow` then try `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

Comment: Found corrupted files with sfc /scannow, Windows couldn't repair it though. Trying dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth now.